Manga or manhwa where the demon lord or king is killed by the hero and goes back in time
In the beginning, the demon lord is bleeding and the hero party surrounds him and he gets stabbed by the hero and goes back in time where he is a noble and lives with his brother, father and stepmom, who all hate him because of his mother. He leaves on a journey after beating his brother and the story continues along the lines of the hero being the devil who turned him into demon lord.

So was the demon lord/king a noble to begin with? I.e. he went back in time and that's who he was when he was younger? Or was he reincarnated as a different person?

Also, was this full colour or mostly black & white?

This is likely The Regressed Demon Lord is Kind.

"Demon King Zeke Mohr, become someone who does good in your next life!" The hero shouted to the Demon King of Power, Zeke, as the Demon King met his demise. When he opened his eyes again, he found himself back as Zeke Steelwill, before he became the demon king. He had no desire to become the successor or the Demon King in this life. Then what? Yeah! Maybe I’ll do "good" like that hero said! But how do you do that? The former Demon King of Power was unfamiliar with the concept of "kindness."

The story opens with the protagonist being defeated by the hero's party, who proclaim him to be a demon lord. While he's bleeding out, the hero lectures him and the protagonist takes this chance to use a fate-altering item on the hero, which ends up sending him into the past.
He awakens as a child, the son of a count. He promptly punches a servant for disrespecting him, then hits a knight over the head with a flower vase when he comes to investigate. He is then summoned by his father and confronted along with his half-brother and stepmother, who take the opportunity to insult his mother.
This leads to a duel with the knight captain, followed by another with his half brother over the heirship of the county. He was initially weak at this point in time but uses his combat experience and knowledge of mana to defeat both, and promptly leaves the family instead of actually accepting the heirship.
I can't confirm that the hero led to him becoming a demon king in the first place, but since the item was used on the hero, it is implied that their fates are connected somehow.
